# Integrated webcam in Dell laptop does not work on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, dell, webcam, cheese

My integrated laptop webcam does not work on Ubuntu 18.04. I have a DELL Latitude E7240.

Can anybody help me troubleshoot the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You will need the package `libuvc0` (USB Video Class library) installed, at a minimum. There may be other requirements as well.

`libuvc0` will also install `guvcview` as a dependency. That is a simple viewer, which will allow you to test whether your system can access your camera. You can start `guvcview` from a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

For Dell Laptop, Please ensure you have secure boot disable by pressing F2 on boot menu.

Comment: How is Secure Boot related to webcam?

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for contributing, but please only answer questions where you know you have a good answer. Secure boot is not likely to be related to this issue. Once you have sufficient reputation you'll be able to comment on questions if you'd like more information.